# If Statement for Time & User defined columns

Tags: vba, outlook

**Updated code 3**

My new code only runs without `+ ReceivedTime > 4`

I receive an error message with this statement. The error is *"Run Time Error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set"*

So far the overdue column is only populated with "No" as the 4 hours are not included.

I believe that the Debug.Print wasn't correct for what I wanted so removed this.

`+ ReceivedTime > 4` doesn't seem correct for finding out if the ReceivedTime is more than 4 Hours?

```
For Each msg In myCollection
    '
    'check if received time is > than 4 hours
    If str2 = "A" Then
        'If str2 = "A" + ReceivedTime > 4 Then
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(4))
        objProperty.value = "Yes"'Set objProperty.str4 = "Yes" 'set Overdue column to say Yes

    Else
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(4))
        objProperty.value = "No" 'if this is not over 4 hours; display No
    End If

    msg.Save
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Should the hour statement be something like the following

```
If str2 = "Create Customer" And ReceivedTime.MailItem = Hour > 4 Then 
    Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(4))
    objProperty.value = "Yes"
```

I receive a run time error for this too.

_________________________________________________________________________-

---

**Original Question:**

I would like an If statement for a User Defined Field Column in Outlook called "Overdue".

If an email is selected and has the value of "A" in UDF 2 and the flag status is not marked as complete; then there is a timer of 4 hours for this task to be completed- but the task timer should start as soon as the mail item reaches the mailbox.

If this is not overdue, then Column "Overdue"(UDF4) will stay as "No", if this is Overdue; >4 hours, this column will be set as the value "Yes"

Below is the code.

**Previous Code**

```
For Each msg In myCollection

    'check if received time is > than 4 hours
    If str2 = "A" + ReceivedTime > 4 Then
        msg.str4 = "Yes" 'set Overdue column to say Yes
    Else
        msg.str4 = "No"
    End If
    Debug.Print "Set objProperty"
    If (objProperty Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print "Set objProperty"
    End If
End If
Debug.Print "objProperty.value"
msg.Save
Next
End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried to rearrange your logic so that it at least has some indentation. I've also moved a few `end if` statements to make the code structurally correct. Whether it is now logically correct is another matter. Indentation makes it easier to see where the`For .. Each` and `if .. end if` blocks are. Not sure what the initial `If .. end if` is for?

Comment: Thank you.. i want to check if the flag status was complete so i assumed this would be an If statement, to say if this is marked as complete then end if: do nothing.. but if the flag status is not marked as complete then to check the amount of hours and if the email set completion is overdue

Comment: OK. I've moved the `end if` to the correct place. Your thinking is sound in that the initial `if` is required to detect the flag setting. In this case the flag detecting `If ... end if` block surrounds all the rest of the logic. This will only be executed if the flag is not set. Note I've changed the condition to `<> oFlagComplete`

Comment: It would be a good idea to set a breakpoint in this code and step though it in debug. You will then see how each logic pocket is processed. You will also be able to see what values are being processed.

Comment: @MiguelH, rearranging code in the question itself is very bad practice.  Write up corrected code in an *answer*, rather than editing the question.

Comment: @MiguelH Thank you, I added a breakpoint and i recieve an error message which says "Compile Error: Next without For" I'm not sure what this means, is the next without for to do with the Ifs and whether they are ended correctly?

Comment: Hi @Soneeka, Can you replace the code in your original question with your new code? A "Next without For" error message either means that you have an extra Next statement OR the Next has been misplaced in logic

Comment: Hi @MiguelH I have updated my code :)

Comment: You appear to have one too many `End If` statements.  There are three `If  ...` but four `end if`

Comment: @MiguelH Thanks, I removed the last one, i now receive an error message "Block If without End If"

Comment: Is there any logic that  logic preceeds this? I'm still not sure what your first `if ..end if` is doing. I would expect to see some logic between these two lines. Have you tried the code structure suggested by@niton? This is structured correctly

Comment: @niton code runs but doesn't seem to populate the column

Answer (score 1):

There should be the same number of If and End If statements inside the loop. I did not get what you were doing with objProperty but it is not needed to illustrate the If End If structure.

```
For Each msg In myCollection

    If msg.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete Then

        'check if received time is > than 4 hours
        If str2 = "A" + TaskDueDate = ReceivedTime > 4 Then
            msg.str4 = "Yes" 'set Overdue column to say Yes
        Else
            msg.str4 = "No"
        End If

        Debug.Print "Set objProperty"
        'Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(4))

        If (objProperty Is Nothing) Then
            Debug.Print "Set objProperty"
            'Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(udf(4), olKeywords)
        End If

    End If 

    Debug.Print "objProperty.value"
    'objProperty.value = "No"`

    msg.Save

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this :). This code runs but doesn't populate the "Overdue" Column

Comment: There is no attempt to populate the "Overdue" column. You will find it useful to learn debugging techniques such as Debug.Print. See here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx